# Can I get an AlertDialog from the onPostExecute() displayed in another activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity, android-alertdialog

When my app gets started it executes an AsyncTask, which checks a page, for a never version of this app. If so, it displays an AlertDialog. But right after the UpdateCheck gets executed, the MainActivity starts a new Intent and a new Activity and so the Alertdialog of the AsyncTask won't get displayed until I return to the MainActivity. Is there a way around to show it independend of the Activity or something like a global Dialog? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you set the `Context` of the `Dialog` to the new `Activity`?

Comment: if the dialog is that important why not just delay the new activity until the user has reacted to the dialog

Comment: I think, you can create an activity, which replaces the dialog and add it in your flow of activities.

Comment: I don't know, probably it would be possible if the context is static, but I'm planning to ad new activitys, and then I don't know how to make it dynamic.

Comment: It is not so important, but the user normally doesn't return to the MainActivity because it's a one-time login Screen.    Hm, is there something like `getCurrentView()` ?